# Exclude users whose names contain

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell

I am trying to automate my O365 licensing and have had some success, but I am not sure how I can accomplish the following...

I have users who I do not wish to license and they all share the value "svc" in their DisplayName.

In trying to test how this would work I'm dumping the values returned out to a [CSV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values) file, but no matter what I do I cannot exclude users with those values in their names. I can do a "contains" and it finds just them...but when I try a "notcontains" I just get all of the users including those with "svc" in their name.

How can I exclude users that have "svc" in their names? Here is my code...

```
$SyncUser = get-msoluser -all | Where-Object { $_.isLicensed -ne "TRUE" }

Foreach ($a in $SyncUser){

    if ($a.DisplayName.NotContains("svc")) {

        add-content -value ($a.Userprincipalname) -path $Logfile
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could exclude these users like this:

```
$users = get-msoluser -all | Where-Object { (-not $_.isLicensed) -and  ($_.DisplayName -notmatch "svc")}
```

**References**

[about_Comparison_Operators](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847759.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
$SyncUser = get-msoluser -all | Where-Object { $_.isLicensed -ne "TRUE" }
Foreach ($a in $SyncUser){
    if ($a.DisplayName.Contains("svc") -eq $False) {
        add-content -value ($a.Userprincipalname) -path $Logfile
    }
}
```